# Looking for a .NET Configuration Framework

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, frameworks

Due to my next project (much SOA stuff) I need a component based configuration and stored in a database to enable a central administration. app.config/web.config does not support any of those requirements (I know some hacks with app-domains, though). So does anybody of you know a configuration framework? It does not necessary have to be free of cost.

I know how to google ;-) but I'd appreciate some experiences about a framework you already used.

Thanks in advance!
Flo

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I also work on a big SOA project. We are using [**Nini**](http://nini.sourceforge.net/) and it is quite good.

Here are some of the features :

- Multiple configuration types INI,
  XML, Registry, and command line
- Strong variable types String,
  int, float, etc. Eliminates casts
- Set and save Add, remove, edit,
  and save configs
- Lightweight and fast Small
  footprint, built for speed
- Merging Merge several configs
  into one
- 100% free Free and open source
  code
- Value aliases Add aliases for
  unclear variables
- Key value replacement Replaces
  values with other key values
- Cross platform Run on .NET/Mono
  Linux/Mac/Windows
- INI parser Contains a 100%
  managed INI parser
- Fully documented See the Nini
  manual and API reference
- Unlimited files/sources Loads an
  unlimited number of files
- Compact Framework Supports the
  .NET Compact Framework
- Command line application Has a
  command-line configuration editor
- Mature and stable Over 140 unit
  tests

Have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'm just flying through the docs. Do you know if it supports any kind of database based configuration?

Comment: AFAIK currently it supports INI Files, XML Files, Windows Registry,  .NET Configuration Files and Command Line (Argv) Configuration.

Comment: Does not really support databases, though, they show a stupidly simple way to work with databases. Take XML and stored in a DB cell ;-). That's fine for me, so thanks again!