# Replacing configuration frameworks, looking for an alternative

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, frameworks

I've been using the following home-grown configuration frameworks to manage configuration of my projects for a few years now:

1. The first one mimics Java's `.properties` files (a bunch of `supergroup.subgroup.property=value` lines with support for collections) and works fine for many situations (I find it's best for small applications). This one is good for very simple configuration
2. A second based on `DataContractSerializer` (and optionally `XmlSerializer`) which allows all of the functionality of the first one with all of the perks of XML and fewer plumbing to make it work. This one is good but impractical and cumbersome to manage without an explicit UI over the top of it to mitigate the headaches of teaching end users to modify XML.

Both of the existing frameworks marshal to and from POCOs without issue to allow access to configuration values through properties/fields (through manual/automatic serialization respectively), so they are very easy to work with as a developer.

Now that I am reviewing their ability to enable database and fluent configuration, I'm looking for an out-of-the-box (preferably open source) alternative. I have no problem with reworking all of my existing projects if I can reduce unnecessary code duplication and allow them access to DB and fluent configuration (in addition to their existing abilities).

Any suggestions or is it worth rolling my own to get the features I'm after?

In my research I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329222/looking-for-a-net-configuration-framework) potentially duplicate question which is answered by [Nini](http://nini.sourceforge.net/) but it hasn't been updated in almost 2 years and only supports the options I already have covered (based on its documentation anyway). Did I miss something in my research or is there a better alternative?

**Update**

The explicit features I'm after are:

- XML files
- INI/Java-like `properties` files
- Database (at least MS SQL and SQLite, optionally MySQL and any others as you could imagine)
- Fluent (code generation not required)
- Some sort of extension API to allow me to add my own sources
- It definitely needs to serialize to/from any of the data sources to be accessible through properties/fields.
- Enumeration support

I'd be interested in extending an existing framework if it is open enough to do what I need to do, but otherwise it probably isn't a good fit.

---

**UPDATE**

The functionality from the existing `System.Configuration` namespace is great, and I'm familiar with how well it can work but in general it doesn't do what I am looking for. I've used it (even in advanced scenarios) but being that it only allows limited XML extensibility: it just isn't what I am after.

If I have to give on any of the predefined functionality, I'd say the fluent configuration is the least important (it'd be extremely difficult to provide a valuable interface for this generically anyway). I'll just bolt together something on top of whatever I find.

The mere fact that it has been over 24 hours (and > 125 views) and no one has been able to offer a reasonable alterative tells me it likely doesn't exist. I'll start on my own in hopes that someone can provide an interesting alternative.

Comment: Can you explicit the features you are after? Access to DB (which mean storing configuration into a central repository, I guess) and fluent configuration. Anything else?

Comment: @VincentHubert - Updated with minimum requirements.

Comment: in terms of project rework, keep in mind Interface Not Implementation - IMHO, this is the kind of thing where you create an interface that defines how you want your code to be able to interact with whatever happens to be the current configuration framework.  Then if something doesn't meet all your needs, you can just 'fill in  the gaps' to get the interface implemented

Comment: @JamesManning - Absolutely. I'd prefer something IoC/DI based but that is definitely something I could implement in their framework later (if there is a good open source alternative) Interface-first design is something I've come to know-and-love, however, I'm not opposed to alternatives.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the "why" behind your list of requirements. *If* the need for database support is so you can have a centralised configuration store that can be accessed from multiple computers, then an alternative option is to use something like curl (http://curl.haxx.se/) to download a configuration file from a website. I have taken this approach in my Config4* configuration-file parser library (http://www.config4star.org/).

Comment: @CiaranMcHale - The _why_ behind my requirements is driven by the fact that there is not (nor should there be) "one configuration format to rule them all". Different projects have different configuration requirements, I'm just looking for a tool to add to my toolbox that can cover as many of the possibilities that I commonly see. If it doesn't exist then I'll build it (like everyone else apparently does). cURL would be a good option if I was going to do this in C++ or Perl, lucky for me .NET has a worthwhile replacement out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a general purpose configuration manager is very very demanding task. Over the years, I haven't seen any config framework emerging and I don't thing I will. Just have a look at the [System.Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.aspx) namespace and you can see how expensive It would be to try to match a similar set of features. Most of the time, configuration requirements are very project specific and there is no silver bullet.

My advice would be to stick to your own solution, as long as it is easily unit-testable and does the job.

Comment: I agree that creating one would be very time consuming including hours of beating my head on my desk. I also agree that a _one size fits all_ solution out-of-the-box is an unreasonable request and custom code will likely still have to be written/generated. That's why I asked about a configuration _framework_ rather than a configuration _manager_. Ideally it would be more like WCF; a series of tinker toys that can be glued together in different ways to achieve a common goal, you just have to make the glue yourself.

Comment: Didn't come across such a framework either (though over the years I've built quite a collection or relevant classes). By the way, even the word 'like WCF' is scary (given the size of WCF!).

Comment: Neither have I, unfortunately. +1 for giving the rational (read: sane) answer, but I'm going to keep looking for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Please check it out [Cinchoo Configuration Framework](http://www.cinchoo.com), it offers most of the features you looking for.

Here is the simple way to define and use the configuration object using Cinchoo framework

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
    #region NameSpaces

    using System;
    using Cinchoo.Core.Configuration;

    #endregion NameSpaces

    [ChoConfigurationSection("sample")]
    public class SampleConfigSection : ChoConfigurableObject
    {
        [ChoPropertyInfo("name", DefaultValue="Mark")]
        public string Name;

        [ChoPropertyInfo("message", DefaultValue="Hello World!")]
        public string Message;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SampleConfigSection sampleConfigSection = new SampleConfigSection();
        Console.WriteLine(sampleConfigSection.ToString());
    }

}
```

Very first time, when you run the application, Cinchoo framework automatically generates the configuration section as below. Then onwards, you can control them either through configuration source or by code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="sample" type="Cinchoo.Core.Configuration.ChoNameValueSectionHandler, Cinchoo.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b7dacd80ff3e33de" />
  </configSections>
  <sample>
    <add key="name" value="Mark" />
    <add key="message" value="Hello World!" />
  </sample>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have for you comes within the Spring Framework .NET, which among other greats features have the *PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer* class.

This class aims to externalize some of the properties you have in your xml config files. So, instead write down literal values (like connection strings, passwords, or any other parameters) you put placeholders, like ${sql.server}, ${sql.password} that will be automatically replaced by the external values.

Those external values can be in anywhere. In my company's case, since we have legacy system that uses the same values, we've put them in the windows registry (which I obviously not recommended for new projects).

But, be aware that this is not a standalone feature of Spring, it comes with Spring.Core, and you will have to use the spring configuration files and Dependency Injection features.

http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-factory-placeholderconfigurer

Comment: It appears that it only works with XML, which is pretty far from what I'm looking for and the prospect of integrating _all_ of the other frameworks into it sounds like a whole lot of work. I'll definitely take a harder look at it though since you said your company is using it for registry configuration. Do you know what the amount of effort was to make it work? Even though it requires more than what I'm after, it might provide a decent model for my efforts.

Comment: Well, the main effort is to put Spring working in your project. If you do not have any previous experience with Spring, it can be a little tricky and even painful. But, in my opinion it worth. I created a very very simple example and put on google code if you want to see an example (http://code.google.com/p/spring-net-placeholder-example/). Hope it helps.